# Dynamically change crossbar.io authorization

Tags: python, autobahn, crossbar

I am using crossbar.io and would like to modify realm-role authorization permissions on the fly via the Management API. The excerpt below is from http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization.

> Crossbar.io can be dynamically reconfigured via the Management API.
>   This includes the ability to reconfigure the authorization and permissions.

So, this seems possible. Can anyone confirm or provide an example (preferably using a Python client ApplicationSession) of how to do so?

Comment: I actually wrote a complete dynamic authentication and authorization application for Autobahn a few months ago (on pypi, sqlauth). There are two hooks needed for the router, one to do the authentication call, and one for the authorization calls.  It's not supported, though, routing was removed from Autobahn and moved to Crossbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this is possible, but it is totally unsupported right now (**Jan. 2015**) since it will *change soon*.

The docs are "misleading" users in this respect and we shouldn't have documented the management API as it is at all (the specific functions to create/remove realm roles and permissions are missing in the docs anyway).

I have now added a warning to this page http://crossbar.io/docs/Management-API/ - Please come to our mailing lists if you like to discuss, tell us your requirements or simply express your anger;) I am sorry, but this (Crossbar.io) is still fast moving ..